# How do you solve $y'=\sin(y)$?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

> How do you solve $y'=\sin(y)$?

I ended up with
$$-\ln(\csc(y)+\cot(y)) = x+C$$

But then I simplified it to
$$e^{-x+C} = \frac1{\sin(y)} + \frac{\cos(y)}{\sin(y)}$$

Where do I go from here?

Comment: You should use the trigonometry identity: $\frac{\sin y}{1+\cos{y}} = \frac{2\sin\frac{y}{2}\cos\frac{y}{2}}{1 + (2\cos^2 \frac{y}{2} - 1)} = \frac{2\sin\frac{y}{2}\cos\frac{y}{2}}{2\cos^2\frac{y}{2}} = \tan\frac{y}{2}$

Answer (score 4):

It is better to write
$$-\log(\csc y+\cot y)=\log\tan\frac y2$$
Then we have
$$\log\tan\frac y2=x+K$$
$$\tan\frac y2=Ae^x$$
$$y=2\tan^{-1}Ae^x$$

Comment: At some point your $y$'s became $x$'s.

Comment: @Ian Right, I committed a thinko there.

Answer (score 2):

It's better to use [the Weierstrass substitution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_substitution#Geometry) :
$$I=\int \dfrac {dy}{\sin y}=\int \dfrac {1+t^2}{2t}\dfrac {2}{1+t^2}dt$$
$$I=\int \dfrac {dt}{t}=\ln t +C= \ln \left|\tan \dfrac y 2 \right|+C$$
Where $t=\tan (y/2)$

Answer (score 1):

$$y'=\sin y\iff\frac{dy}{\sin y}=dx\iff \int\frac{dy}{\sin y}=\int dx\implies$$

$$\implies\ln\tan\frac y2+c\implies$$

$$\implies\tan\frac y2=e^{c+x}\implies \frac y2=\arctan\left(e^ce^x\right)\implies\ldots$$

Comment: I don't understand the question: *those* **are** all the possible values of the solution function $\;y=f(x)\;$ ...If you have some intial condition then the constant $\;C\;$ could be found...Maybe you mean that since $\;0<\arctan x<\frac\pi2\;$ for all $\;x\in (0,\infty)\;$ , then in this case  $\;0<y<\pi\;$ for all $\;x\;$ ...?

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for any integer $k$, the constant function $y(x)=\pi k$ is a solution because

$$\sin\left(y(x)\right)=\sin(\pi k)=0=y'(x)$$

To find the others, we may assume that $y(x)$ is not of the form $\pi k$. Then $\sin(y(x))$ is not identically zero, so

$$\csc(y(x))y'(x)=1$$

Antiderivatives of $\csc(y(x))y'(x)$ and $1$ are given by $-\tanh^{-1}\left[\cos(y(x))\right]$ and $x$, so these two must differ by a constant, say $c$.

$$-\tanh^{-1}\left[\cos(y(x))\right]=x+c$$

We can now solve equation for $y(x)$. As always, $c$ was redefined to absorb the minus sign.

\begin{align*}
\tanh^{-1}\left[\cos(y(x))\right] &= c-x\\
\cos(y(x)) &= \tanh(c-x)\\
y(x) &= 2\pi k\pm\cos^{-1}\left[\tanh(c-x)\right]
\end{align*}

In the last line, we made use of the not-so-easy-to-prove fact that for $|y|\leq 1$,

$$y=\cos(x)\iff x=2\pi k\pm\cos^{-1}(y)$$

In summary, the solutions are

$$y(x)=\pi k$$

and

$$y(x) = 2\pi k\pm\cos^{-1}\left[\tanh(c-x)\right]$$